# SocketId is changed after saving it to database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, socket.io

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
   socket.emit('online');
   users.findOne({'username':session.username},function(err,user){
   console.log("UPDATING THE CURRENT SOCKEDID ie ! "+" socketidfromDB :  
   "+user.callsession.socketid+"    to cureent socketid :  "+socket.id);
   user.callsession.socketid=socket.id;
   user.save();
});
```

When I am trying to run this piece of code on connection of socketio, This automagically runes two times and end up saving wrong socketId to DataBase. The socketId stored is not the current socketId, Its something Else.
[image]

What is happening ?

Comment: You shouldn't save `socket.id` in the database as it changes whenever client connects with the server.

Comment: @MukeshSharma I am trying to implement a calling system like hangouts, I need to store socketid to the data base to make a call connection to the user,

Comment: What about the case when user disconnect for a while and then reconnect ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma That will not be an issue, as I am updating the user's socketid everytime he connects. Do you have any better way to do this ? -

Comment: Yes, instead of saving it mongodb, you can save it in some cache/system's memory to have better latency.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to pass session token in data through socket. You can easily trace all communication for respective session. It's difficult to relay on socket id which adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: But How would I be able to communicate with specific socket client?

Comment: You can always conned to the socket client the way you connect currently. What I am proposing is whenever u pass any data model through socket client, add one property to your data json which holds the session id or token which uniquely identify the user.  And relay on that token instead of socket id.